What can we say about the average order of group members of alternating group?
I asked this question in other community of the website but I have not got any answer.
During an ongoing research I dealt with the concept of orders of group members. The following question remained a gap in my analysis. Any insight is appreciated.
Let $ \bar{o}(G) $ be the average order of the elements of $ G $, where $ G $
is a finite group.
Let $ A_n $ be the alternating group of degree $ n $. Then
\begin{align*}
&      \bar{o}(A_3)\simeq 2.33,   \quad  \quad  \bar{o}(A_4)\simeq 2.58, \quad \quad     \bar{o}(A_5)\simeq 3.51,  \quad\quad     \bar{o}(A_6)\simeq 3.91, \\
&       \bar{o}(A_7)\simeq 5.00,   \quad  \quad  \bar{o}(A_8)\simeq 6.79,  \quad  \quad    \bar{o}(A_9)\simeq 8.35,  \quad \quad    \bar{o}(A_{10})\simeq 9.98, \\
&       \bar{o}(A_{11})\simeq 11.18,   \quad    \bar{o}(A_{12})\simeq 12.41, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{13})\simeq 14.86, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{14})\simeq 19.17, \\
&         \bar{o}(A_{15})\simeq  24.04,  \quad      \bar{o}(A_{16})\simeq  27.97,  \quad     \bar{o}(A_{17})\simeq 29.11,   \quad    \bar{o}(A_{18})\simeq 32.01,  \\
&       \bar{o}(A_{19})\simeq  37.56, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{20})\simeq  43.47, \quad \bar{o}(A_{21})\simeq  54.14, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{22})\simeq  63.11,
 \\
&       \bar{o}(A_{23})\simeq  66.35, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{24})\simeq  70.22, \quad \bar{o}(A_{25})\simeq  81.97.
 \end{align*}
My question:
If $n \geqslant 13$, show that $\bar{o}(A_{n}) >  n+1$

It is important that you give references to these previous questions on other sites like this one : please realize that knowing the important comments  that have been given to you at that time avoid to restart from scratch...

Is $ \bar{o}(G) $ just the sum of all element orders divided by the group order? So $\bar{o}(A_3)=\frac{7}{3}$, instead of  $2.33$? Try to find elements of maximal order in $A_n$ and count how many there are. It might be already enough.

The result of Goh and Schmutz for the average order $\mu_n$ of an element of $S_n$, i.e.  $\log \mu_n \sim c\sqrt{n/\log n}$ for a constant $c$  as $n \to \infty$ certainly implies that the average order of an element of $A_n$ exceeds any polynomial function of $n$ for sufficiently large $n$, but I have no idea how to estimate what "sufficiently large" means.
